# JQuery 1.7.1 seemingly can't handle HTML5 element IDs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, sizzle

As you may be aware, [HTML5 allows more characters to be used in ID names](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) - see [the HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute) which now has space as the only invalid character. Attempting to use this with JQuery shows JQuery ignoring all characters in the ID after a particular valid character, '/'.

```
<section>
    <div id='foo/bar'>
        YAAY
    </div>
    <div id='foo'>
        BOO
    </div>
</section> ​
```

Logging the 'foo/bar' element

```
console.log(​$(document).find('div#foo/bar')​​​​)​
```

Shows the incorrect element being returned:

```
[
<div id=​"foo">​
    BOO
​</div>​
]
```

This is using both the current stable JQuery (1.7.1) and the current JQuery edge.

Is this a JQuery bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is there a question hidden somewhere?

Comment: @Christoph Added question to clarify that I'm asking if this is a JQuery bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Next time, just use this tool: http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0foo%2Fbar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the slash (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m9NT8/):

```
console.log(​$(document).find('div#foo\\/bar')​​​​)​
```

PS. `$(document).find('selector')` is equivalent to `$(selector)`.

This behaviour is defined in a RegEx at [Sizzle's source code, line 374](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L374):

```
ID: /#((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF\-]|\\.)+)/,
```

Comment: That works. Further research shows that JQuery mentions the need to escape characters for selectors on http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ "If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes" Annoying, but oh well.

Comment: Ack re: document.find, in my (non stackoverflow test case) app I'm working off a string in memory, rather than the document.

Comment: Ah, that was the trick :D Sorry for that, I will delete my previous comment.