# jQuery("#"+id) Vs document.getElementById(""+id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I have following id for one of my div `id="ftbutton_1357567084/Team:8/User:10/Image:195"` i want to replace its html after ajax being called.

When i try to do this using jQuery something like following it doesn't work

```
jQuery("#"+id).html(SOME HTML HERE);
```

Where as following code works

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = SOME HTML HERE;
```

I know ID should not contain some special characters

```
ID attributes should be = after an initial letter (a-z or A-Z), may also use 
periods and colons, in addition to letters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores.
```

Ref [`How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation?`](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F)

But for some reason i can't change the id of each element as it is thought the site.

I also tried following but it doesn't works

```
function jq( myid ) {
  return "#" + myid.replace( /(:|\.)/g, "\\$1" );
}
jQuery(jq("#"+id)).html(SOME HTML HERE);
```

I just want to know if this is a case, do i need to use `document.getElementById(""+id)` instead `jQuery("#"+id)` ?

OR in other words

Is `document.getElementById(""+id)` is more reliable than `jQuery("#"+id)` ?

Comment: Escape the `/` as well. All characters listed in http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Comment: Do a http://jsFiddle.net/ Then you can play around with the id and see if it is your special chars that don't work!

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750670/jquery-1-7-1-seemingly-cant-handle-html5-element-ids

Comment: In your jq() function, you shouldn't return extra '#' as it make double  '##' as you are using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're adding the `#` twice. Once in the function and once in the actual `jQuery` call. Should be like this:

```
function jq( myid ) {
  return "#" + myid.replace( /(:|\.|\/)/g, "\\$1" ); //note that added `/`
}
jQuery(jq(id)).html(SOME HTML HERE); //don't add # again!
```

**A slightly unrelated tip:** always remember you can initiate a jQuery instance using an actual DOM object:

```
jQuery(document.getElementById(someId)); //this will work
```

Comment: Thanks.....i also check by removing `"#" +` from `function jq( myid )`......but still it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Salil Notice that you have to escape the `/` as well. See how I edited the Regex in `jq` above.

Answer (score 7):

Do this:

`$('[id="ftbutton_1357567084/Team:8/User:10/Image:195"]');`

It's actually a bit of an interesting question. Most likely jQuery thinks `:` is initiating a filter, like `$('div:visible')` and getting gunked up not realizing it's a full ID.

Comment: He is escaping the `:` though.

Comment: wish I could +1 again for your edit! This is meta-data shoehorned into an id :grr:

Comment: Fabulous Answer......works for me :) Will accept as soon as i able to......Thanks a Ton

Comment: Just note that this is obviously slower than using an ID selector.

Comment: This is, IMHO, overkill and does not resolve the actual question on why his current method doesn't work. It's also slower as @FelixKling mentioned.

Comment: @Andy Ray:- +1 for your answer but accepting `Abody97` answer as it seems faster. thanks for your answer though. I wish i could accept two answers :(

Answer (score 2):

[`/` is a meta character, you have to escape it as well](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`.

So this should work fine:

```
function escape_selector( selector ) {
  return selector.replace( /([!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~])/g, "\\$1" );
}
```

(As [roasted mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254651/jqueryid-vs-document-getelementbyidid/14254825#comment19782277_14254651), you need to drop the `'#' +` as well, otherwise you add it twice to the selector).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QEPCK/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer seems to be:

```
function jq( myid ) {
  return $(document.getElementById(myid));
}

jq(myid).html(...);
```

Comment: I believe that's already kinda mentioned in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14254924/364869).

Comment: Ya, its just to clarify and i think its the best way/fastest to do it

Answer (score -4):

the correct function is:

```
function jq( myid ) {
  return *$("#" + myid)*.replace( /(:|\.)/g, "\\$1" );
}
jQuery(jq("#"+id)).html(SOME HTML HERE);
```

Comment: No, he does not want to select any element inside the function, he wants to modify the string to make it a proper selector. Besides, the code would throw an error because jQuery does not have a `.replace` method.